# Python synchronize subclass threads

Tags: python, multithreading

First of all, I'm new to `threading` in Python and actually pretty new to Python in general, so please excuse if the question is not well asked.

I have 2 modules that each include one class. These classes are both subclasses of `threading.Thread`. I start these two threads from a third module, `main.py`:

```py
from controller import Controller
from server import Server
from ultrasonic import Ultrasonic

if __name__ == "__main__":
    controller = Controller()

    server = Server(controller)
    server.start()

    ultrasonic = Ultrasonic(controller)
    ultrasonic.start()
```

As you can see, both threads access another class in a different module, `Controller`. To make sure the two threads won't interfere while calling methods of `Controller`, I want to synchronize these threads. I saw, that there's the option of using `threading.Lock`, but I'm not sure how to implement this in my specific case, with different subclasses of `threading.Thread` in different modules.

I hope y'all can help me. Thank you!

**EDIT:**
The methods in the `Controller` class look like this:

```py
def stop(self):
    GPIO.output(self.LEFT_PIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(self.LEFT_PIN2, False)
    GPIO.output(self.RIGHT_PIN1, False)
    GPIO.output(self.RIGHT_PIN2, False)
```

I thought it might lead to problems if the GPIO pins recieved contrary signals. If that's not the case, then I don't need to synchronize the threads in the first place.

Comment: Please update your question with an example (perhaps made-up) of a method of `Controller` which needs synchronisation.

Comment: As a general statement, if the shared resource is the controller, try to make it thread-safe by putting locks in the relevant places.

Comment: @quamrana I edited the question. I thought it may be a problem if the GPIO pins recieve contrary signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your Controller class could create a `Lock`:

```
from Threading import Lock

class Controller:
    lock = Lock()    # class level instance

    def stop(self):
        Controller.lock.acquire()
        GPIO.output(self.LEFT_PIN1, False)
        GPIO.output(self.LEFT_PIN2, False)
        GPIO.output(self.RIGHT_PIN1, False)
        GPIO.output(self.RIGHT_PIN2, False)
        Controller.lock.release()
```

This way the Controller class creates a single `Lock` when it is defined.

When any call is make to `stop()`, the current thread `acquires` the lock and releases it upon return. Any other thread which makes it to the `acquire()` call, blocks until the first thread releases it.

Better is to use context management and the `with` statement:

```
    def stop(self):
        with Controller.lock:
            GPIO.output(self.LEFT_PIN1, False)
            GPIO.output(self.LEFT_PIN2, False)
            GPIO.output(self.RIGHT_PIN1, False)
            GPIO.output(self.RIGHT_PIN2, False)
```

Note that I've used a `Lock` at the class level since you are locking access to the `GPIO` pins of your processor and there will only be one set of those.

Comment: Thank you! Is a class variable preferable to an instance variable? I thought I read somewhere that instance variables are the more "pythonic" way to do it

Comment: Its not a python thing its a design thing. If you make the `lock` an instance variable now and later you make two instances of the `controller`, then two threads could each concurrently enter the `stop` method.